# Create a function that takes an object and a key as input - return value for key within the object

Tags: javascript

Just learning JS, came across this question on coursera. I can't even begin to answer this question; I'm not certain what it's asking. Sorry for the ignorance. Just looking for the basic format. I can write a function that takes input, but not certain how to do this. I've spent a while researching objects and it's not quite sinking in yet. Thanks!

Comment: Which part exactly are you struggling with? And what have you tried doing?

Comment: Simple answer: you shouldn't. Function calls are expensive and you can get the value directly from the obj.

Comment: I'm not certain how to ask for an object and key as input; I can make an object and keys, but am struggling with getting that from the user and returning it. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question? Seems strange.

Comment: You don't need to ask anything from the user (according to what you posted), it's just a function that takes two parameters (one being the object, the other they key)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple parameters. You need to separate the parameters with commas like:

```
function func(param1, param2) {
    console.log("Parameter 1: " + param1);
    console.log("Parameter 2: " + param2);
}
func(1, 2);
// Console:
// Parameter 1: 1
// Parameter 2: 2
```

In actual code this would look like the following:

```
function getValue(object, key) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(key) returns if the specified object has the specified key in it 
        return object[key];
    } else {
        // The else statement is not really needed as the function already returned
        // if the object has the specified key
        return null;
        // If you need this function for something specific, then you should return a default value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clean and clear:

```
function f(obj,keyname){
    return obj[keyname];
}
```

Usage: `f(myObj,my_key_field_name)`

or simply `obj[keyname]` if you do not like to write a function